# How create new array which subtracts values from 2 double arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, subtraction

Helou it's my problem, I have 2 array which have double values:

(this is function which get back values(latitude) from richTextBox)

```
  private Tuple<double>[] szerokosc(string[] lines)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll(lines, line =>
        {   
            string[] elems = line.Split(',');
            double we = 0.01 * double.Parse(elems[3], EnglishCulture);
            int stopnie = (int)we;
            double minuty = ((we - stopnie) * 100) / 60;
            double szerokosc_dziesietna = stopnie + minuty;
            return new Tuple<double>(Math.Round(szerokosc_dziesietna, (int)numericUpDown2.Value));
        });
        ;
    }
```

(this part of code call function)

```
var data1 = szerokosc(szerdlugeo_diag_gps.Lines);
var data2 = szerokosc(szerdlugeo_diag_gpsglonass.Lines);
```

What should I do, to get something like this:

for example: var data3 = data1 - data2;

My values in this data looks like (f.e.)
data1 = (x11, x12, ... x1(n) ):

```
53.11818160073043,
53.11816348903661,
53.11814874695463,
...
```

data2 = (x21, x22, ... x(2n) ):

```
53.11814200771546,
53.118131477652156,
53.11812263239697,
53.11811884157276,
53.11811631435644,
....
```

I would like back data3 = (x31=x11-x21, x32=x12=x22, ... x(3n)=x(1n)-x(2n) )

It would be good if it included the following condition:
if 
data1 = (  1,   5,   6, 8)
data2 = (1.5, 3.3)

data3 = (-0.5, 1.7) not data3 = (-0.5, 1.7, 6, 8)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays are both the same length and of type `double[]` then LINQ makes this easy with [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;
// …

var result = data1.Zip(data2, (d1, d2) => d1 - d2).ToArray();
```

The passed lambda function is applied to each successive pair of elements from the two arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but hmm I have error:
"Error 1 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Tuple<double>' and 'System.Tuple<double>"

Comment: @TomekeM: Note the first paragraph of this answer, and then in your question you strongly imply this is the case (albeit this does not completely match the code sample: ie. your Q is not consistent). But just adjust the lambda's expression to extract the correct member: eg. `(d1, d2) => d1.Item1 - d2.Item2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is next part of my code. I'm using it to plot a chart which shows difference in latitude between receiver GPS and receiver GNSS. Maybe it will be helpful for someone. Thanks for help with "var result = data1.Zip ..." :)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data1 = szerokosc(szerdlugeo_diag_gps.Lines);
        var data2 = szerokosc(szerdlugeo_diag_gpsglonass.Lines);

        var data_finish = data1.Zip(data2, (d1, d2) => d2.Item1 - d1.Item1).ToArray();

        var minimalna1 = data_finish.Min();
        var maksymalna1 = data_finish.Max();

        chart9.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minimalna1;
        chart9.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maksymalna1;

        Series series333 = new Series("DGPS") { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line, BorderWidth = 1, MarkerSize = 3, MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square, Color = Color.Blue };
        foreach (var p in data_finish)
            series333.Points.Add(p);
        chart9.Series.Add(series333);
    }
```